# How to find a matrix of a linear transformation from $P_2$ to $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $F : P_2 → P_3$ be the linear mapping given by $F(p(x)) = \int_{0}^{x}p(t) dt$. Find the
matrix of $F$ with respect to the basis {$1, x, x^2$} of $P_2$ and the basis {$1, x, x^2, x^3$} of $P_3$.

I don't even know how to start this question. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(1)=x \\
F(x)= \frac{1}{2} x^2 \\
F(x^2) = \frac{1}{3} x^3$$
So the matrix will be:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$