# Verification of answer to forming a matrix from a linear transformation plus proving surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

The original question reads:

Let $H : P_3 → P_1$ be the linear mapping defined by $H(p(x)) = \frac{d^2p}{dx^2}$. Find the matrix of $H$ with respect to the basis {$1, x, x^2, x^3$} of $P_3$ and the basis {$1, x$} of $P_1$.

My answer was as follows:

$H(1) = 0, H(x) = 0, H(x^2) = 2, H(x^3)=6x$.

Hence forming the matrix: 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this correct?

Secondly, I need help proving that this transformation $H$ is surjective. Any pointers/ help on how to do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. It is a map from a space with dimension $4$ into a space with dimension $2$, and so the answer cannot be a $4\times4$ matrix. The answer is:$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&6\end{bmatrix}.$$And, yes, $H$ is surjective. Since the range of $H$ contains both $2$ and $6x$, it contains all of their linear combinations. And the set of all their linear combinations is $P_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Can I ask, how do you know whether to map the resulting vectors from the transformation applied to each basis vector as column vectors or row vectors in the resulting matrix?

Comment: For example, if you refer to my last question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429686/how-to-find-a-matrix-of-a-linear-transformation-from-p-2-to-p-3/3429715#3429715
You will see that the vectors are listed as column vectors in the matrix rather than row vectors.

Comment: I just used the definition of [matrix of a linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: Hold on, I'm being silly. You have inserted the columns, but removed the bottom two rows. My new question is why can you remove those two rows? Sorry.

Comment: I did not remove any row. When I saw that your answer had a $4\times4$ matrix I new that it was wrong, and that's it; I did not look at your matrix again until I computed the answer. And the computations I did were:\begin{align}H(1)&=0=0\times1+0\times x\\H(x)&=0=0\times1+0\times x\\H(x^2)&=2=2\times1+0\times x\\H(x^3)&=6x=0\times1+6\times x.\end{align}This is where the entries of my matrix come from.